# Group based time difference analysis for large dataset with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a large dataset (roughly 250k rows) with property ID numbers and survey response datetimes. I'm trying to build some kind of basic fraud detection and one of the factors I'm considering is response time between different surveys for each property/store. If there is less than 10 minutes between any surveys for a particular location, I want it flagged as TRUE under a column called "close_response".

I have nested for loops within a function that is applied to each group that achieves what I want, but it's computationally expensive and time consuming when applied to a very large dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'property_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        'response_datetime': ['2023-10-19 08:00:00', '2023-10-19 08:05:00', '2023-10-19 08:25:00', '2023-10-19 09:00:00', '2023-10-19 09:15:00', '2023-10-19 10:00:00', '2023-10-19 11:00:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['response_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['response_datetime'])

def mark_close_responses(group):
    group['close_response'] = False
    for i in range(len(group)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(group)):
            time_diff = group.iloc[j]['response_datetime'] - group.iloc[i]['response_datetime']
            if time_diff <= timedelta(minutes=10):
                group.at[i, 'close_response'] = True
                group.at[j, 'close_response'] = True
    return group

df = df.groupby('property_id').apply(mark_close_responses)
```

Comment: IIUC within each group you just want to compare consecutive timestamps and check if they are within a threshold? Why do you need a nested loop for this?

Answer (score 3):

Compute the difference between successive rows using `diff`, get rows from the difference that are less than or equal to 10 minutes, use a conditional to get accurate positions per group, back fill and assign back to the original dataframe:

```py
difference=df.groupby('property_id').response_datetime.diff()
out = difference.le(pd.Timedelta(minutes=10))
out = difference.where(difference.isna(), out).bfill()
df.assign(close_response=out)
   property_id   response_datetime  close_response
0            1 2023-10-19 08:00:00            True
1            1 2023-10-19 08:05:00            True
2            1 2023-10-19 08:25:00           False
3            2 2023-10-19 09:00:00           False
4            2 2023-10-19 09:15:00           False
5            3 2023-10-19 10:00:00           False
6            3 2023-10-19 11:00:00           False
```

Comment: It doesn't work when the first row that matches that condition isn't actually the first row of the dataframe. If you add another row above 2023-10-19 08:00:00, say 2023-10-18 08:00:00, 2023-10-19 08:00:00 won't have True applied to it. I had a similar issue when I tried using diff before on my own. I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: Kindly share an updated example with expected output

Answer (score 1):

one more piece of code to achieve result

```
import pandas as pd

df['response_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['response_datetime'])

def mark_close_responses(group):
    time_diff = group['response_datetime'].diff().le(pd.Timedelta(minutes=10))
    group['close_response'] = time_diff | time_diff.shift(-1, fill_value=False)
    return group

df = df.groupby('property_id').apply(mark_close_responses).reset_index(drop=True)
```